# hide all but one element of certain class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an effect whereby clicking on a title toggles the corresponding content div. Clicking on another title while some content is showing should hide that content div and show the content div corresponding to the title just clicked.

However the code is not doing anything, as you can see on the following jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/dPsrL/

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
    <div class="row title">
    <div class="title" industry_id="education">Ed</div>
    <div class="title" industry_id="tech">Tech</div>
    <div class="title" industry_id="finance">Fin</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row content">
    <div class="content" id="education">Education is great</div>
    <div class="content" id="tech">Technology is awesome</div>
    <div class="content" id="finance">Finance is super</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').hide();
});

('.title').on('click', function () {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('industry_id');
    alert(clicked);
    $("#"+clicked).toggle(400);
    $("#"+clicked).siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: Typo on `('.title')`. Should be `$('.title')`. Also, you should probably not give the container divs the same class as the child divs and then use that same class in your CSS and jQuery. It just makes selection more difficult.

Comment: You were right on both counts, please submit as answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo on `('.title')`. Should be `$('.title')`. Also, you should probably not give the container divs the same class as the child divs and then use that same class in your CSS and jQuery. It just makes selection more difficult.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v4g7X/)**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of toggling the clicked element first and then hiding the others, why don't you just hide everything first and then show the clicked one? Saves you a check, and all you have to do is switch the order

```
$('.title').on('click', function () {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('industry_id');
    alert(clicked);
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + clicked).show(400);
});
```

Comment: Hey Stephan, I needed to make sure a second click on the same title div would also hide its content div, which Is not feasible easily if we were to start by hiding all of them and then toggling.

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute doesn't have the `id selector` in it. You need to do a string concatenation  :

```
$('.title').on('click', function () {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('industry_id');
    alert(clicked);
    $('#' + clicked).toggle(400);
    $('#' + clicked).siblings().hide();
    //The two last lines could be :
    //$('#' + clicked).toggle(400).siblings().hide();
});
```

Also you have to remove the class `content` and `title` on the `row` since it trigger the click event and the hide part.

Here's a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dPsrL/3/

Comment: sir, where is your id selector? he just missed a $

Comment: Thanks, however the toggle and sibling().hide() parts still don't work

Comment: @Max updated my answer. You have to remove some classes.